# How to grid search parameter for XGBoost with MultiOutputRegressor wrapper

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm trying to build a regressor to predict from 6D input to a 6D output with `XGBoost` with the `MultiOutputRegressor` wrapper. But I'm not sure how to do the parameter search. My code looks like this:

```
gsc = GridSearchCV(
            estimator=xgb.XGBRegressor(),
            param_grid={"learning_rate": (0.05, 0.10, 0.15),
                        "max_depth": [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 8],
                        "min_child_weight": [ 1, 3, 5, 7],
                        "gamma":[ 0.0, 0.1, 0.2],
                        "colsample_bytree":[ 0.3, 0.4],},
            cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', verbose=0, n_jobs=-1)

grid_result = MultiOutputRegressor(gsc).fit(X_train, y_train)
self.best_params = grid_result.best_params_
```

However, the `MultiOutputRegressor` has not `.best_params_` variable. What's the right way to do so? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this

```
gsc = GridSearchCV(
            estimator=xgb.XGBRegressor(),
            param_grid={"learning_rate": (0.05, 0.10, 0.15),
                        "max_depth": [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 8],
                        "min_child_weight": [ 1, 3, 5, 7],
                        "gamma":[ 0.0, 0.1, 0.2],
                        "colsample_bytree":[ 0.3, 0.4],},
            cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', verbose=0, n_jobs=-1)

grid_result = MultiOutputRegressor(gsc).fit(X_train, y_train)

self.best_params = grid_result.estimators_[0].best_params_  # for the first y_target estimator
```

Comment: sorry for the late comment, it works, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

`MultiOutputRegressor` have at the estimator itself and the `param_grid` need to changed accordingly.

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor

X_train, y_train = make_regression(n_features=6, n_targets=6)

gsc = GridSearchCV(
            estimator=MultiOutputRegressor(XGBRegressor()),
            param_grid={"estimator__learning_rate": (0.05, 0.10, 0.15)},
            cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', verbose=0, n_jobs=-1)

grid_result = gsc.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(grid_result.best_params_)

# {'estimator__learning_rate': 0.1}
```

Comment: I tried, but there is an error: ValueError: Invalid parameter learning_rate for estimator MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=XGBRegressor(base_score=None, booster=None,...

Comment: So I suspect that the parameters are set for MultiOutputRegressor in this way, but MultiOutputRegressor doesn't have these parameters.

Comment: ValueError: Invalid parameter learning_rate for estimator MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=XGBRegressor(base_score=None, booster=None,
                                            colsample_bylevel=None,...),
                     n_jobs=None). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

Comment: please let me know if you have any idea @Venkatachalam, thank you!!

Comment: can you create a reproducible error with this dataset `X_train, y_train = make_regression(n_features=6, n_targets=6)`

Comment: hope noted the change I recommended in the `param_grid`, `param_grid={"estimator__learning_rate": (0.05, 0.10, 0.15)}`